# Should most questions be tagged with the book they are asking about?

Tags: discussion, tags

For example should [*What is the Hermeneutical significance of the lack of direct mention of God in Esther?*](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/864) be tagged [esther](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esther) rather than (or in addition to) [old-testament](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/old-testament)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, [esther](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esther) for a question localized to the book, and [old-testament](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/old-testament) only for questions that relate to the OT in general. It would be unusual but not impossible to tag both [esther](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esther) and  [old-testament](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/old-testament), for example in this hypothetical question:

"What significance does the book of Esther have in the overall plot of the Old Testament"